# Permissions in wordpress running on Cent OS VPS - unable to update theme/plugin/wordpress

Tags: wordpress, centos, vps

I am running wordpress 4.0 on Cent OS powered VPS. The installation runs smoothly, in my admin dashboard I see updates for wordpress/plugins/themes .I am facing the following errors when I try to upgrade them from dasboard

**Updating Wordpress to 4.1 from 4.0**

```
Update WordPress

Downloading update from https://downloads.wordpress.org/release/wordpress-4.1-new-bundled.zip…

Unpacking the update…

Could not create directory.

Installation Failed
```

**Updating Plugins**

```
Update Plugin

Downloading update from https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/google-sitemap-plugin.2.9.5.zip…

Unpacking the update…

Could not create directory.
```

**Updating Themes**

```
Updating Theme Twenty Fourteen (1/1)

Downloading update from https://downloads.wordpress.org/theme/twentyfourteen.1.3.zip…
Unpacking the update…

An error occurred while updating Twenty Fourteen: Could not create directory.

All updates have been completed.
```

I know I am messing with the file permissions, I have tried setting the permissions for the files as well. I tried assigning them to various groups/users like apache,root and nginx.

These are the current file permissions for my wordpress directory.

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 apache apache  3070 Jan  2 10:59 wp-config.php
drwxr-xr-x 12 apache apache  4096 Jan  1 23:31 wp-includes
drwxrwxrwx  6 apache apache  4096 Jan  1 22:37 wp-content
drwxr-xr-x  9 apache apache  4096 Jan  1 22:31 wp-admin
-rwxr-xr-x  1 apache apache   435 Jan  1 22:25 index.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 apache apache 19930 Jan  1 22:25 license.txt
-rwxr-xr-x  1 apache apache  7290 Jan  1 22:25 readme.html
-rwxr-xr-x  1 apache apache  3824 Jan  1 22:25 sitemap.backup.xml
-rwxr-xr-x  1 apache apache  5082 Jan  1 22:25 wp-activate.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 apache apache   289 Jan  1 22:25 wp-blog-header.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 apache apache  5110 Jan  1 22:25 wp-comments-post.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 apache apache  2826 Jan  1 22:25 wp-config-sample.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 apache apache  3071 Jan  1 22:25 wp-cron.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 apache apache  2460 Jan  1 22:25 wp-links-opml.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 apache apache  2787 Jan  1 22:25 wp-load.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 apache apache 34185 Jan  1 22:25 wp-login.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 apache apache  8512 Jan  1 22:25 wp-mail.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 apache apache 11489 Jan  1 22:25 wp-settings.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 apache apache 27005 Jan  1 22:25 wp-signup.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 apache apache  4153 Jan  1 22:25 wp-trackback.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 apache apache  3132 Jan  1 22:25 xmlrpc.php
```

Please guide me for suitable permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having the same issue... Did you try disabling all your plugins? Also you could try to change your permission to 777